# Spring Boot application starts faster when deployed inside Docker containers

Tags: spring-boot

Today I observed a strange behavior of our applications, which is built using Spring Boot.

I thought containerizing applications in Docker would slow down the startup time. However, when I ran the application, the dockerized actually booted 10% faster (the results were taken from Spring Boot's logs). I repeated the test with ~10 other Spring Boot applications and received the same result.

I can not understand this, some of you may have better insights?

Note: I ran the jar file with normal "java -jar" commmand, and the docker container with "docker run"

Comment: My question is how it is even possible? I would think that Docker adds another "layer" on the Spring Boot's jar and slows down the startup process.

Comment: there is s differene between docker container starting and application inside docker container starting. usually when you start docker container, it almost immediately starts and gives you the return code. But for the application inside it to start, it takes the same amount of time. do recheck

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

I checked the logs of Spring Boot to determine the startup time. This log looks like: 

`Started Application in 9.143 seconds (JVM running for 9.806)`

And the value displayed with dockerized appplication is smaller than the value displayed when I start the applcation from JAR file.